# Send form params to controller without a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a form:

```
 <%= form_for(:user_email, :url => {:action => 'send_email'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:subject, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.button "Submit", type: 'submit'%>
<% end %>
```

And a controller:

```
class UserEmailController < ApplicationController
   def send_email
      p params[:subject]
   end
end
```

This writes `nil` in the console instead of the text I put in my textfield.

Question: How can I access the content of my fields in the controller?

I should mention that the action itself is triggered, but the parameters are nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
p params[:user_email][:subject]
```

And if that doesn't produce what you're looking for, try:

```
p params
```

... to inspect what's getting sent over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Use [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) with your path. I have used `/user_email/send_email`. change it according to the route your have setup in `routes.rb`

```
 <%= form_tag('/user_email/send_email') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:subject, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```